# How to use grep in .zip file

Tags: linux, shell

There are 3 files a.csv,b.csv,c.csv zipped as abh.zip, now is it possible to execute grep command on abh.zip (is there any wild card by which only grep run for c.csv file inside zip).

Answer (score 12):

If you have `zipgrep` (which, AFAIK, is shipped with the `zip` utilities), then you can simply do

```
zipgrep "pattern" abh.zip c.csv
```

`zipgrep` supports most of the same basic options as vanilla `grep`.

Alternatively, if you don't have `zipgrep` but you have `unzip`, you can do

```
unzip -p abh.zip c.csv | grep "pattern"
```

which unzips the file to a pipe (`-p`) then sends it to be `grep`ped.

Answer (score 1):

you can run zipgrep command with pip operator as below.then you can only set name"

> zipgrep "name" abh.zip | grep c.csv