# How to grep on the content of a zipped non-standard textfile

Tags: linux, grep, unzip

On my Windows-10 PC, I have installed Ubuntu app. There I'd like to grep on the content of a group of zipfiles, but let's start with just 1 zipfile. My zipfile contains two files: a crashdump and an errorlog (textfile), containing some information. I'm particularly interested in information within that error logfile:

```
<grep_inside> zipfile.zip "Access violation"
```

Until now, this is my best result:

```
unzip -c zipfile.zip error.log
```

This shows the error logfile, but it shows it as a hexdump, which makes it impossible to launch a grep on it.

As proposed on different websites, I've also tried following commands: `vim`, `view`, `zcat`, `zless` and `zgrep`, all are not working for different reasons.

**Some further investigation**

This question is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30885072/608639), a suggested, I believe the issue is caused by the encoding of the logfile, as you can see in following results of other basic Linux commands, after unzipping the error logfile:

```
emacs error.log
... caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)

cat error.log
. . . c a u s e d   a n   A c c e s s   V i o l a t i o n   ( 0 x c 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 )
```

Apparently the error.log file is not being recognised as a simple textfile:

```
file error.log
error.log : Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use grep in .zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30885072/608639), [How to use grep command on zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25624801/608639), [How can I grep for a text pattern in a zipped text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1249798/608639), [Searching for a string on multiple zip files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18552/56041), etc.

Comment: In order to grep in a ZIP file you have to unpack the file, because the ZIP directory is at the end of the file. So use `mktemp -d`, `unzip`, `grep` and `trap` to remove the extracted files at the end.

Comment: @Dominique It is useless to avoid it, because every tool, your try to find, has to do exactly the same job. And you just want a tool, the question is offtopic here, because it belongs to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this post on grepping non-standard text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752913/grepping-binary-files-and-utf16), I found the answer:

```
unzip -c zipfile.zip error.log | grep -a "A.c.c.e.s.s"
```

Now I have something to start from.

Thanks, everyone, for your cooperation.